# Add raster dataset saved through a partitioned table in PostgreSQL to QGIS layers

Tags: qgis, raster, postgresql, partition

I have a big raster dataset that are fragmented to smaller TIFF files. I want to store and access this dataset via PostgreSQL database. To avoid storing all about 20 GB data in one table that causes performance degradation, I decided to use table partitioning in PostgreSQL. A sample of a simple code for this is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE public.my_rasters (
rid bigint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
file_name varchar(150),
rast raster,
CONSTRAINT my_rasters_pk PRIMARY KEY (rid, file_name)
) PARTITION BY LIST (file_name);

CREATE TABLE public.my_rasters_1
PARTITION OF public.my_rasters
FOR VALUES IN ('file1.tif');

CREATE TABLE public.my_rasters_2
PARTITION OF public.my_rasters
FOR VALUES IN ('file2.tif');
```

After that, I stored contents of 'file1.tif' and 'file2.tif' in `my_rasters` using raster2pgsql as follows:

```
raster2pgsql -n file_name "path_to_file\file1.tif" -a public.my_rasters | psql -h localhost -U username -p 5432 -d dbname

raster2pgsql -n file_name "path_to_file\file2.tif" -a public.my_rasters | psql -h localhost -U username -p 5432 -d dbname
```

The contents of file1.tif and file2.tif was stored in tables: my_rasters1 and my_rasters2 respectively. In QGIS I can access the parent table 'my_rasters' and its children: 'my_rasters1' and 'my_rasters2' using a PostgreSQL connection. The contents of all these tables can be viewed in *tabular form* using `Execute SQL` option.

But the problem is when I drag these tables to canvas or in layers panel, just child tables (my_rasters1, my_rasters2) are added and shown correctly and the parent table (my_rasters) that integrates contents of its children, are not shown in canvas. In the layers panel, a caution icon are visible alongside the added parent table that when the mouse is hovered on it a message appear:

> Unavailable layer! Layer data source could not be found. Click to
> set a new data source.

[image: adding parent table (my_rasters) to layers has error]

The version of my PostgreSQL is 14.1 and the postgis_raster extension is 3.2.0.
The version of QGIS is 3.28.8.
What is the problem and is it possible to be solved?